Is 'or other' in 'a choice of reactive libraries (Reactor, RxJava, or other).' proper?

If you are already shopping for a non-blocking web stack, Spring
WebFlux offers the same execution model benefits as others in this
space and also provides a choice of servers (Netty, Tomcat, Jetty,
Undertow, and Servlet containers), a choice of programming models
(annotated controllers and functional web endpoints), and a choice of
reactive libraries (Reactor, RxJava, or other).

Google's results suggest that 'or other' is often used with uncertain words, such as 'some'(eg.'some antique shop or other','someone or other') and etc.,but there are not such words in the cited sentence above.
So, I want to know whether the original sentence -...(Reactor, RxJava, or other)...- is grammatical. If this usge is proper, does 'or other' refer to 'some reactive library' or 'some reactive libraries'?

"and others" might be better if you genuinely have multiple choices. But it's not quite clear what you mean - does the choice of library depend on the other choices?

@Stuart F So, is it right in the original sentence-(Reactor, RxJava, or other)?
